307 temprory redirect, already have 301 and 302 redirect setup
I have already got 301 and 302 redirect set up. I need to setup the 307 temporary Redirect to be setup in http://mysite.local/news, for every news item like http://mysite.local/news/year*/month*/day*/abcd to http://myothersite.local/news/year*/month*/day*/abcd (this is non-sitecore site)
In my opinion in cm

I can see 301 and 302 response statuses created in /sitecore/system/Modules/Redirect Module/Response Status Codes, I created 307 temporary redirect in this folder
for this kind of redirect to all the news item should I use redirect pattern or redirect rule?
I tried using the redirect pattern it is not working


This is not sxa or jss sitecore.
What shall the source item value be if I shall be using redirect pattern?

In order to redirect to external url using regex pattern rule, you will need to modify the RedirectProcessor class inside the Redirect module to handle the redirection for external url's, as this is not available OOTB.
Inside the RedirectProcessor processor class, there is a method name CheckForRegExMatch that handles the logic for redirection using regex pattern. Modify this method as below.
private void CheckForRegExMatch(Database db, string requestedUrl, string requestedPathAndQuery, HttpRequestArgs args)
{
  // Loop through the pattern match items to find a match
  foreach (Item possibleRedirectPattern in GetRedirects(db, Constants.Templates.RedirectPattern, Constants.Templates.VersionedRedirectPattern, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting(Constants.Settings.QueryExactMatch)))
  {
     var redirectPath = string.Empty;
     if (Regex.IsMatch(requestedUrl, possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.RequestedExpression], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
     {
        redirectPath = Regex.Replace(requestedUrl, possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.RequestedExpression],
                                                possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.SourceItem], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     }
     else if (Regex.IsMatch(requestedPathAndQuery, possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.RequestedExpression], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
     {
        redirectPath = Regex.Replace(requestedPathAndQuery,
                                                possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.RequestedExpression],
                                                 possibleRedirectPattern[Constants.Fields.SourceItem], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     }
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectPath)) continue;

     // Added else condition to redirect for external url's

     if (redirectPath.Contains("/sitecore/content"))
     {
        var pathAndQuery = redirectPath.Split('?');
        var path = pathAndQuery[0];
        var redirectToItem = db.GetItem(path);
        if (redirectToItem == null)
        {
           if (LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlBuilderOptions() != null && (bool)LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlBuilderOptions().EncodeNames)
           {
              path = Sitecore.MainUtil.DecodeName(path);
           }
           redirectToItem = db.GetItem(path);
        }
        if (redirectToItem != null)
        {
           var query = pathAndQuery.Length > 1 ? "?" + pathAndQuery[1] : "";
           var responseStatus = GetResponseStatus(possibleRedirectPattern);
           SendResponse(redirectToItem, query, responseStatus, args);
        }
      }
      else
      {
         var responseStatus = GetResponseStatus(possibleRedirectPattern);
         var pathAndQuery = redirectPath.Split('?');
         var query = pathAndQuery.Length > 1 ? "?" + pathAndQuery[1] : "";
         SendResponse(redirectPath, query, responseStatus, args);
      }
   }
}

Inside above code, condition is added to redirect to external urls when the source item does not contains /sitecore/content path. Once the above changes are made, you can configure redirect to external url's using regex pattern as below.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
